# Android: How to position the screen on a part of a view which has bounds greater then the screen?

Tags: android, achartengine

I am using an aChartEngine GraphicalView to show up a bar chart. I am not using the aChartEngine's 'pinch to zoom'. The behavior is that the chart zooms in on first tap and then if a bar of the chart is tapped, a more granular chart for that bar is shown.

For the zoom I am using the Zoom tool provided by aChartEngine. On tap I call the zoomIn method for the bar chart and it's working well. (The zoom is only on the X axis)

The problem I am facing is that it always zooms in to the center of the chart irrespective of where I tap. So, to tap a bar at the edge i have to pan to the corresponding bar to select it. What i want to do is that if the user taps on the edge of the chart the chart, on zooming in, should show that region of the chart.

For example, if the x axis initially showing values from 1 to 30. If the user taps to zoom around the 3rd bar, the resulting chart shows bars from 12 to 18 even though he has tapped around the 3rd bar. I want to be able to show bars 1 to 6 so that he directly has the view of the 3rd bar, and if he wants he can pan to other bars as well.

P.S. - The zoom method of the aChartEngine is using scales to set the range and stuff. Can setting the scale limits help in this regard? I couldn't understand the multiple scales funda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually   there is not any function to achieve this . If you want to achieve this you have to edit the source of library .

Make a new function in `Zoom.java`(Only change in value of `centerX` & `centerY`)

```
public void apply(int zoom_axis,double x,double y) {
    if (mChart instanceof XYChart) {
      int scales = mRenderer.getScalesCount();
      for (int i = 0; i < scales; i++) {
        double[] range = getRange(i);
        checkRange(range, i);
        double[] limits = mRenderer.getZoomLimits();

        double centerX = x;
        double centerY = y;
        double newWidth = range[1] - range[0];
        double newHeight = range[3] - range[2];
        double newXMin = centerX - newWidth / 2;
        double newXMax = centerX + newWidth / 2;
        double newYMin = centerY - newHeight / 2;
        double newYMax = centerY + newHeight / 2;

        // if already reached last zoom, then it will always set to reached
        if (i == 0) {
          limitsReachedX = limits != null && (newXMin <= limits[0] || newXMax >= limits[1]);
          limitsReachedY = limits != null && (newYMin <= limits[2] || newYMax >= limits[3]);
        }

        if (mZoomIn) {
          if (mRenderer.isZoomXEnabled() && (zoom_axis == ZOOM_AXIS_X || zoom_axis == ZOOM_AXIS_XY)) {
            if (limitsReachedX && mZoomRate < 1) {
              // ignore pinch zoom out once reached X limit
            } else {
              newWidth /= mZoomRate;
            }
          }

          if (mRenderer.isZoomYEnabled() && (zoom_axis == ZOOM_AXIS_Y || zoom_axis == ZOOM_AXIS_XY)) {
            if (limitsReachedY && mZoomRate < 1) {
            } else {
              newHeight /= mZoomRate;
            }
          }
        } else {
          if (mRenderer.isZoomXEnabled() && !limitsReachedX
              && (zoom_axis == ZOOM_AXIS_X || zoom_axis == ZOOM_AXIS_XY)) {
            newWidth *= mZoomRate;
          }

          if (mRenderer.isZoomYEnabled() && !limitsReachedY
              && (zoom_axis == ZOOM_AXIS_Y || zoom_axis == ZOOM_AXIS_XY)) {
            newHeight *= mZoomRate;
          }
        }

        double minX, minY;
        if (limits != null) {
          minX = Math.min(mRenderer.getZoomInLimitX(), limits[1] - limits[0]);
          minY = Math.min(mRenderer.getZoomInLimitY(), limits[3] - limits[2]);
        } else {
          minX = mRenderer.getZoomInLimitX();
          minY = mRenderer.getZoomInLimitY();
        }
        newWidth = Math.max(newWidth, minX);
        newHeight = Math.max(newHeight, minY);

        if (mRenderer.isZoomXEnabled() && (zoom_axis == ZOOM_AXIS_X || zoom_axis == ZOOM_AXIS_XY)) {
          newXMin = centerX - newWidth / 2;
          newXMax = centerX + newWidth / 2;
          setXRange(newXMin, newXMax, i);
        }
        if (mRenderer.isZoomYEnabled() && (zoom_axis == ZOOM_AXIS_Y || zoom_axis == ZOOM_AXIS_XY)) {
          newYMin = centerY - newHeight / 2;
          newYMax = centerY + newHeight / 2;
          setYRange(newYMin, newYMax, i);
        }
      }
    } else {
      DefaultRenderer renderer = ((RoundChart) mChart).getRenderer();
      if (mZoomIn) {
        renderer.setScale(renderer.getScale() * mZoomRate);
      } else {
        renderer.setScale(renderer.getScale() / mZoomRate);
      }
    }
    notifyZoomListeners(new ZoomEvent(mZoomIn, mZoomRate));
  }
```

Also in `GraphicalView.java`

```
public void zoomIn(double x,double y ) {
    if (mZoomIn != null) {
      mZoomIn.apply(Zoom.ZOOM_AXIS_XY,x,y);
      repaint();
    }
  }
```

Now use this in ur `onclick()`

```
mChartView.zoomIn(mChartView.toRealPoint(0)[0],mChartView.toRealPoint(0)[1]);
```

Comment: Been busy so couldn't come back on this. I did the same for the problem. It is working well. One thing you will have to take care of is the pan bounds. For example, if the panning bound on x axis is say 0 and we center the chart at 0 then the panning does not work since it is at the bound. So you will have to make sure that you adjust chart for this boundary case. I did the same. Basically you will have to adjust the center in this case.